# ARM assembly output isn't functioning correctly

Tags: arm

This is supposed to output the contents of each line in arm assembly. Though line 18 `add r4, r5, r4, lsl #1` isn't being outputted correctly and I am not sure why.

```
    .data
    str1: .asciz "%d and %d are the results \n"
    n: .word word 1
    .text 
    .global main 
    main: stmfd sp!, {lr} 
    ldr r4,=n
    ldr r4, [r4]
    add r4,r4, #1
    mov r1, r4
    ldr r0, =str1
    bl printf 
    mov r5, r4
    mov r1, r4
    mov r2, r5
    ldr r0, =str1
    bl printf
    add r4, r5, r4, lsl #1
    mov r1, r4
    ldr r0, = str1
    bl printf
    ldmfd sp!, {lr}
    mov r0, #0
    mov PC, or
    .end
```

Comment: huh...……........

Comment: I get a 1542060288 as a final value.

Comment: If you want help with debugging, you will need to tell us what you expect the output to be, what it was when you ran the code.

Comment: I was expecting 4 given the logical shift left on the aforementioned line.